# solving two uncoupled ODEs within a loop using python and scipy.integrate.ode

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am having problem for solving two very easy uncoupled ODEs using scipy.integrate.ode. For instance this following simple code:

```
from scipy.integrate import ode

def f(t, y, r_r=1.68,mu_ext=0. ,tau_m=0.020, tau_s=0.005, gs= 0.5):
        dmu = (1./tau_s)*(-y[0] + mu_ext + gs*r_r)
        dx = (1./tau_m)*(-y[1] + y[0])
        return [dmu, dx]

t0 = 0.0                #Intial time
y0 = [4.0, 0.0]         #initial condition for x = 0
y1 = [4.0, 1.0]         #inital condition for x = 1

x0m = ode(f)
x0m.set_initial_value(y0, t0)

x1m = ode(f)
x1m.set_initial_value(y1, t0)
t1 = 1.0
dt = 0.0001

x0 = []
x1 = []

t=0

for i in xrange(1000):
        t +=dt
        x0m.integrate(t)
        x0.append(x0m.y)
        x1m.integrate(t)
        x1.append(x1m.y)
```

Interestingly, each one can be solved perfectly in two different loops but I don't understand why this makes the second ODE solver return nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I ran your code in ipython I got:

```
Integrator `vode` can be used to solve only
a single problem at a time. If you want to      
integrate multiple problems, consider using 
a different integrator (see `ode.set_integrator`)
```

Apparently you have to use:

```
ode.set_integrator
```

to integrate multiple problems at the same time

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. The documentation of it is very poor! How can I use ode.set_integrator to solve my problem?

Comment: It seems it would also work with runge-kutta method, if I set my solver to work with “dopri5”.

Comment: If you look at pg 270 of the documentation: [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/scipy-ref.pdf) it says that the runge-kutta method is the only mode that supports integrating multiple ODEs at the same time.

Comment: Looks like the pdf-with-explicit-page-numbers document is gone. [This exists](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html) but is for v0.17 explicitly.