# Multiple scipy.integrate.ode instances

Tags: python, scipy, python-multithreading, ode, odeint

I would like to use **scipy.integrate.ode** (or scipy.integrate.odeint) instances in **multiple threads** (one for each CPU core) in order to solve multiple IVPs at a time. However the documentation says: "*This integrator is not re-entrant. You cannot have two ode instances using the “vode” integrator at the same time.*"

(Also odeint causes internal errors if instantiated multiple times although the documentation does not say so.)

Any idea what can be done?

Comment: Have you seen [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574146/solving-two-uncoupled-odes-within-a-loop-using-python-and-scipy-integrate-ode#comment36180664_23574361) and the corresponding posts? Also, odeint [might no be susceptible](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.scientific.user/36151) to the same problem.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Thanks for looking at it! The link to the .pdf did not work anymore. However I rather need an implicit solver than an explicit one and Runge Kutta is an explicit one, I think. I also got internal errors when I tried to use mutithreaded odeint rather than ode. I think `ode.set_integrator('lsoda')` is the same implementation as odeint.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option is to use [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) (i.e. use processes instead of threads).  Here's an example that uses the `map` function of the `multiprocessing.Pool` class.

The function `solve` takes a set of initial conditions and returns a solution generated by `odeint`.  The "serial" version of the code in the main section calls `solve` repeatedly, once for each set of initial conditions in `ics`.  The "multiprocessing" version uses the `map` function of a `multiprocessing.Pool` instance to run several processes simultaneously, each calling `solve`.  The `map` function takes care of doling out the arguments to `solve`.

My computer has four cores, and as I increase `num_processes`, the speedup maxes out at about 3.6.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

import sys
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint



def lorenz(q, t, sigma, rho, beta):
    x, y, z = q
    return [sigma*(y - x), x*(rho - z) - y, x*y - beta*z]


def solve(ic):
    t = np.linspace(0, 200, 801)
    sigma = 10.0
    rho = 28.0
    beta = 8/3
    sol = odeint(lorenz, ic, t, args=(sigma, rho, beta), rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-12)
    return sol


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ics = np.random.randn(100, 3)

    print("multiprocessing:", end='')
    tstart = time.time()
    num_processes = 5
    p = mp.Pool(num_processes)
    mp_solutions = p.map(solve, ics)
    tend = time.time()
    tmp = tend - tstart
    print(" %8.3f seconds" % tmp)

    print("serial:         ", end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    tstart = time.time()
    serial_solutions = [solve(ic) for ic in ics]
    tend = time.time()
    tserial = tend - tstart
    print(" %8.3f seconds" % tserial)

    print("num_processes = %i, speedup = %.2f" % (num_processes, tserial/tmp))

    check = [(sol1 == sol2).all()
             for sol1, sol2 in zip(serial_solutions, mp_solutions)]
    if not all(check):
        print("There was at least one discrepancy in the solutions.")
```

On my computer, the output is:

```
multiprocessing:    6.904 seconds
serial:            24.756 seconds
num_processes = 5, speedup = 3.59
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example! That's what I wanted.

Comment: Do you know why the CPU load always corresponds with the number of processes (up to the number of cores) rather than with the set size of the initial conditions?

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  After all, how could the CPU load exceed the number of cores?

Comment: E.g. if the set size of the initial conditions was 2 (i.e. there are two separate ode calculations) and the number of processes 4 (on a 4 core machine) the CPU load would always be 100 % although only 1 core could be used for each ode calculation. I would the CPU load have expected to remain at about 50 % and 2 processes to remain idle.

Comment: Each call to `solve` is run in a single process.  With two sets of initial conditions, the best you can expect is to use two CPUs at 100%.  That's what I see if make ics have shape (2, 3), and I set `num_processes=4`, but I have to make the `t` array large to clearly see it using the Activity Monitor on Mac OS X.  In this case, multiprocessing is only useful if each solution takes a long time, otherwise the multiprocessing overhead time (e.g time to start the processes, time to copy the data between processes, etc) will dominate the overall time.

Comment: If you have just two sets of initial conditions, but you see four cores running at 100% for an extended period, then I don't know what is happening.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have to test long term simulations.

Answer (score 1):

SciPy.integrate.ode appears to use the [LLNL SUNDIALS solvers](https://computation.llnl.gov/projects/sundials/uses-sundials), although SciPy doesn't [say so explicitly](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html), but they should, in my opinion.

The current version of the CVODE ode solver, 3.2.2, is re-entrant, which means that it can be used to solve multiple problems concurrently. The relevant information appears in [User Documentation for CVODE v3.2.0 (SUNDIALS v3.2.0)](https://computation.llnl.gov/sites/default/files/public/cv_guide.pdf).

> All state information used by cvode to solve a given problem is saved in a structure, and a pointer
>   to that structure is returned to the user. There is no global data in the cvode package, and so, in this
>   respect, it is reentrant. State information specific to the linear solver is saved in a separate structure,
>   a pointer to which resides in the cvode memory structure. The reentrancy of cvode was motivated
>   by the anticipated multicomputer extension, but is also essential in a uniprocessor setting where two
>   or more problems are solved by intermixed calls to the package from within a single user program.

But I don't know whether SciPy.integrate.ode, or other ode solvers like [scikits.odes.ode](https://scikits-odes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html), support this concurrency.