# Running scipy.odeint through multiple cores

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, jupyter, odeint

I'm working in Jupyter (Anaconda) with Python 2.7.

I'm trying to get an odeint function I wrote to run multiple times, however it takes an incredible amount of time.

While trying to figure out how to decrease the run time, I realized that when I ran it only took up about 12% of my CPU.

I operate off of an Intel Core i7-3740QM @ 2.70GHz:
https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i7-3740QM+%40+2.70GHz&id=1481

So, I'm assuming this is because of Python's GIL causing my script to only run off of one core.

After some research on parallel processing in Python, I thought I found the answer by using this code:

```
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp


Altitude = np.array([[550],[500],[450],[400],[350],[300]])

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = 4
    p = mp.Pool(processes)
    mp_solutions = p.map(calc, Altitude)
```

This doesn't seem to work though.  Once I run it, Jupyter just becomes constantly busy. My first thought was that it was just a high computation level so it was taking a long time, but then I looked at my CPU usage and although there were multiple instances of Python processes, none of them were using any CPU.

I can't figure out what the reasoning for this is.  I found this post as well and tried using their code but it simply did the same thing:

[Multiple scipy.integrate.ode instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291639/multiple-scipy-integrate-ode-instances)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running it from a terminal instead of from Jupyter?

Comment: could be the shape of your array is confusing the `map`, can you refactor your code so you're just passing in a plain list like `altitude  = [550,500,450,400,350,300]`

Comment: @Warren Weckesser Just the guy I was looking for.  I would've commented on the original post but I don't have the rep.

This completely worked.  Thank you for the suggestion. I should've tried that in the first place. Why do you think it only works in terminal and not Jupyter?

Comment: Greg, I don't know what the problem might be.  You could try searching here and on the jupyter/ipython github pages for issues related to jupyter and multiprocessing, or ask on the ipython mailing list.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser Okay, thank you. Would you like to write an answer to this so I can make it an answered questions? Or should I?

Comment: My suggestion is a work-around for the problem.  I think the real question is why doesn't it work in jupyter, and that doesn't have an answer.   Perhaps a jupyter expert will come along and solve the problem...

Comment: You might want to replace the "function" tag (which seems pretty pointless) with the "jupyter" tag.