# Re-entrant complex ODE solver in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode

I have a list of complex differential equations that I need to step through "in parallel" (integrating one time step for equation 1, then one time step in equation 2, then another on in equation 1, etc): the solver needs to be "re-entrant". I've been trying to use `scipy.integrate.ode`. My problem is
exactly the same as [solving two uncoupled ODEs within a loop using python and scipy.integrate.ode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574146/solving-two-uncoupled-odes-within-a-loop-using-python-and-scipy-integrate-ode#comment36180664_23574361), except with complex differential equations. Thus I can't use the 'dopri5', which is for real-valued ODEs only.

Is there *any* complex re-entrant ODE solver available in Python (preferably with an interface that isn't too radically different from `scipy.integrate.ode`)?

Using `multiprocessing` to have the solver in multiple processes (as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291639/multiple-scipy-integrate-ode-instances)) isn't really an option, because the overhead of sending back the states through IPC would be prohibitive. Another [comment on the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291639/multiple-scipy-integrate-ode-instances) mentions that the sundials-library that underlies the scipy solver actually is re-entrant, but presumably Scipy hasn't caught up. Are there any other Python wrappers for sundials? I can't find any information whether the mentioned [scikits-odes](https://scikits-odes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package is re-entrant.

I also tried simply replacing `scipy.integrate.ode` with `scipy.integrate.complex_ode`, but that crashes with a `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'complex'` that I haven't investigated any further.

My actual code where this entire problem comes up is here:
https://github.com/qucontrol/krotov/blob/fe7c7240b6b7090b176b96f7d6d2f6b96bc39816/src/krotov/propagators.py#L156

Comment: You can always wrap your complex computation by composing the complex input from the first and last half of the real input vector and separating the real and complex parts of the derivative as parts of the result vector.

Comment: Are you sure that you really need to swap back and forth between the different equations and cannot just use one bigger equation comprising the two?

Comment: @LutzL, that's certainly an option, but only as a last resort. I'll have to see how much overhead that'll create.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, combining the different equations is mathematically possible, but doesn't fit into the larger API at all, unfortunately.